# Android Gallery and ImageSwitcher First Image

Tags: android

I have implement Gallery and Image Switcher in Eclipse Android Development.

On click of thumbnail, it loads the image and on click of Set Wallpaper, it sets the wallpaper as well. But as soon as the application loads, I want to display the first image from the Gallery to Image Switcher. Other wise if you click on Set Wallpaper, it will throw an exception. After you select an image from the Gallery, it will work fine.

Can anyone please help me how to show the first image of the gallery in Image Switcher so that when I click Set Wallpaper without selecting an image, it should work fine

One more thing, after image switcher initialization, I have set the first image but it takes the entire window in Emulator? If you select an image it show the preview.

Thanks in advance.